# How to store fetched JSON data with PHP and update it if it was updated longer than 2 hours ago?

Tags: php, fetch

I'd like to fetch JSON data and store it on the server to use it later to request that data in a HTML page. This setup is required to not go over the limit of requests of a free API plan.

How do I set this up with PHP to fetch and store a JSON file and update it every 2 hours (maximum 12 times a day)? There is no need to automate the update, it's perfectly fine if its updated with the next request after the file was updated more than 2 hours ago.

(TLDR: Copy JSON file from an URL with PHP, save it to local server, and update it if was updated more than 2 hours ago)

Comment: Would be much simpler to just automate with a Cron job

Comment: I've never used that before, I've found it in my cpanel, timing is easy to setup, what should I write in the command field?

Comment: Google how to run PHP scripts with Cron and you should get the idea

Comment: I'm not really sure I found the right solution, is it 
` <?php copy( source, destination ) ?> `
?

Comment: Well that's what you might put inside the script file potentially. I thought you were asking how to configure the Cron job, not how to write the code

Comment: yeah, I've actually found out most of the stuff now, I thought the cron job's "command" is the actual php script, now I can set up the job, the only thing thats still not working is I've managed to get the json, it updates on my server every x minutes, its visible if you check it from a browser, but for some reason the same json is not working with the same js fetch as what the original json was working with

Comment: I guess thats some kind of server permission issue?

Comment: Who knows, we don't have any information to understand the issue. "Not working" isn't an error message, or a clear problem description, or any other kind of debugging info. The cause of "Not working"  could be anything from a missing comma in the code to someone switching off the server. It's meaningless. If you need help, provide relevant code, data and debugging info.

Comment: yeah, sorry, it actually works on server, locally not.

Comment: Ok. Still can't help you with that though, you didn't provide any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet the original criteria, where the file did not need to be updated if nobody was requesting it, you can use `filemtime()` to determine when the cached JSON file was last written to.

```
function getCachedJSON( $filename ) {
    $cache_life = 7200; /* Cache Lifespan (in seconds) */
    $json = false;

    $filemtime = @filemtime($filename);  // returns FALSE if file does not exist
    if (!$filemtime or (time() - $filemtime >= $cache_life)){
        /* Go and update the JSON file */

        /* Ensure $json contains the data */

    } else {
        $json = file_get_contents($filename);
    }

    /* Return the JSON or false */
    return $json;
}
```

Be sure to add some proper validation in here if you choose to use it.

Comment: Does this mean that the visitor has to cache the JSON files first?